# Using SOAP login() for authentication in Salesforce oAuth flow

Tags: soap, oauth2

I would like to do a background login of users (using soap login() API) and then use the session to trigger an oAuth flow to receive my access and refresh tokens. Is this feasible and if so how?

Comment: Do you want only soap api callout to get tokens? I have code for SOAP API callout but don't know about `trigger an oAuth flow`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your session token from the login() call interchangeably with access tokens, but you cannot get a refresh token from the login() call; only when you login using OAuth with the appropriate scope can you get a refresh token. You can't trade an access token or session token for a refresh token.